# Incorrect proof of closure under the star operation using NFA results in the NFA recognizing undesired strings?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

I'm currently reading the book *Introduction to the Theory of Computation (2nd or 3rd Ed.)* by *Michael Sipser*, and have stumbled upon a question in *Chapter 1 - Regular Languages*, namely when the author is presenting the proof idea of *Theorem 1.49* - **"The class of regular languages is closed under the star operation."** using NFA.

The approach suggested is that, if we have a regular language $A_1$ and want to prove that $A_1^*$ also is regular, we can take an NFA $N_1$ and modify it into an $N$ as in the image below, which is then a particular NFA recognizing $A_1^*$.

[image: Modifying the NFA $N_1$]

He noted:

> One (slightly bad) idea is simply to add the start state to the set of accept states. This approach certainly adds $ε$ to the recognized language, but it may also add other, undesired strings.

I have drawn the "bad" NFA as below and tried to figure out why this will result in undesired strings. However, I can't find an example of when the an undesired string is recognized. Why will this idea result in the NFA recognizing undesired strings?

[image]

Could someone point this out for me or give me a hint, or have I misunderstood the author? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider a two state automaton for the language $a^*b$, two transitions from the initial state, one looping with label $a$, the other with label $b$ to the final state.

Making the initial state final, would also accept $a^*$.